How to make dialog show up in 3 seconds after event onMouseOver
I have an element and after over mouse on it, i show up additional information
document.getElementById(item.id).getElementsByTagName("div")[0].classList.add(classes.hoverDescription)

 .treeNodeDescription{
    font-family: "liberation-sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #F8F7F7;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130%;
    left: 21%;   
    z-index: 10;
    max-width: 300px;
    text-wrap: wrap;
  }

 .hoverDescription{
    display: block;
  }

But i want to show up this information if user over his mouse along 3 seconds, and if he leave his mouse, don't show up this DIV.
How to do it using js or css?

When he mouses over start a timer.  When he mouses out cancel the timer.  When the timer expires, show the div.  See this question

I don't know why, but when i do this and move mouse on different same divs, it starts to show up without timer

"mouseleave" event instead of "mouseout" so it doesn't trigger when hovering child elements, see this other question

What exactly are these values: item.id and classes.hoverDescription? How can we tell if your layout correlates with the JavaScript? This: document.getElementById(item.id).getElementsByTagName("div")[0].classList.add(classes.hoverDescription) is a code smell. Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>). Add relevant HTML as well.

Plz insert this script tag in your html file.
<script>
    const item = document.getElementById(item.id);
    const description = item.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    let hoverTimeout;

    item.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        hoverTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            description.classList.add('hoverDescription');
        }, 3000); // Show after 3 seconds
    });

    item.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); // Clear the timeout if mouse leaves
        description.classList.remove('hoverDescription'); // Hide the description
    });
</script>


The first line of your JS differs from that in the question, and does something different. Why make that change? Nothing in the question says the id is ’item’.
